# How to disable defining class properties in Babel + transform-decorators-legacy

Tags: javascript, decorator, babeljs

In my library (for AngularJS) I'm trying to implement following functionality:

1. You can mark an empty class property with some decorator
2. During the initialization process this property is replaced with getter defined by `Object.defineProperty`.
3. User can call this property inside the class, and the getter will be called.

But I have met an unexpected behavior in Babel. In Typescript which is used in library, it works well, but Babel creates some bunch of code which redefines already defined properties to it's initializers.

It is the decorated class in ES2015:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test'
})
export class TestClass {
  @Inject('$http') $http;
  @Inject('$q') $q;
}
```

There is the resulting code:

```
var TestClass = exports.TestClass = (_dec9 = (0, _ngMetasys.Component)({
  selector: 'test'
}), _dec10 = (0, _ngMetasys.Inject)('$http'), _dec11 = (0, _ngMetasys.Inject)('$q'), _dec9(_class4 = (_class5 = function TestClass() {
  (0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, TestClass);
  // everything is OK, TestClass.prototype.$http is a getter with function () => $http.

  _initDefineProp(this, '$http', _descriptor5, this); // there are dragons. Property $http is redefined to undefined. 

  _initDefineProp(this, '$q', _descriptor6, this);
}, (_descriptor5 = _applyDecoratedDescriptor(_class5.prototype, '$http', [_dec10], {
  enumerable: true,
  initializer: null
}), _descriptor6 = _applyDecoratedDescriptor(_class5.prototype, '$q', [_dec11], {
  enumerable: true,
  initializer: null
})), _class5)) || _class4);
```

How can I disable this property redefining? Is there a way to avoid babel's property redefining or to substitute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found an answer to my question. There is one test in `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` which allows to set up the descriptor of property, even to transform simple property to a getter.

There is one limitation. If you want to remember decorator to change it later, it will not work. I did not investigate it properly, but I think my problem was the fact I change descriptor after class (and properties) initialization, and changes I make to descriptor do not affect already initialized properties.

So there is the test that gave me the hint. It is from [here](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy/blob/master/test/index.js#L642).

```js
it('should support mutating an initialzer into an accessor', function(){
  function dec(target, name, descriptor){
    expect(target).to.be.ok;
    expect(name).to.eql("prop");
    expect(descriptor).to.be.an('object');

    let {initializer} = descriptor;
    delete descriptor.initializer;
    delete descriptor.writable;

    let value;
    descriptor.get = function(){
      if (initializer){
        value = '__' + initializer.call(this) + '__';
        initializer = null;
      }
      return value;
    };
  }

  class Example {
    @dec
    prop = 3;
  }

  let inst = new Example();

  expect(inst.prop).to.eql('__3__');
});
```